# why web platform installer 5.1 dosent show any products php sql

Tags: windows, iis, server, web-platform-installer

web platform installer  say there are no products or applications availabil to install (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eE2H.png)

i try to reinstall it so many time but it dosent work

Comment: If you spend a few minutes on the tag info, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-platform-installer/info

Answer (score 1):

WPI was retired on December 31, 2022.

IIS Team Blog: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed